# Static HTML to CMS: Same URL structure do I need 301 redirect?

Tags: 301-redirect, cms, static-content

I am transferring a website over from static to CMS and the new CMS will have the same URL structure. Do I need to do any 301 redirects or anything else so I don't impact current ranking. Also if I do find url differences how long should the 301 redirects be kept for.

Answer (score 1):

*This applies to your situation:*

1. If the domain is the same go to 2.
2. If the url's are the same, go to 3.
3. Do nothing and enjoy.

*Summary:*

You only ever need to use a 301 redirect when  changing domain or a url. In the event that you do need to use a 301 redirect then you need to have that as long as the URL exists, its not a tell Google once then remove it... keep it forever.

Comment: I would change step 3 to Drink a beer at the local pub with your friends. ;-) Cheers!!